# Websocket соединения в массиве - норма?

Tags: python, сокет, websocket, socket.io, tornado

Методично прошелся по ссылкам из первой страницы гугла по запросу "tornado chat" и обратил внимание, что во всех примерах соединения пишутся в массив (список, множество... не суть): кто-то объявляет переменную списка еще в начале файла, кто-то в классе приложения, но никто не пишет их в базу.
Это нормально и в production'е оно все так и хранится в общем массиве и этот массив каждый раз обходится в цикле в поисках нужного клиента? Или все-таки я наткнулся на очень учебные материалы и в настоящих приложениях стоит делать как-то иначе?

Comment: Ну, соединения в базу писать технически невозможно :) А так насчёт нормальности не знаю, но в зависимости от задачи можно и словарь вместо массива завести, например; я так в своих велосипедах делаю и пока ничего плохого не заметил

Comment: @andreymal, технически в python есть сериализатор pickle, а у sqlalchemy есть поле типа PickleType, но я при попытке их использовать с экземпляром класса, в котором живет соединение (ну как-то так я себе это представляю), получил  

    Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed  
**upd** хотя, наверное, это и значит "невозможно" :)

Comment: Независимо от pickle (и от питона вообще) все соединения закрываются при завершении процесса операционной системой, поэтому, даже если и записать в базу, например, идентификаторы сокетов (это нетрудно), их всё равно нельзя будет использовать после перезапуска приложения, а без этого хранить соединения в базе просто нет никакого смысла и вполне хватит функциональности массива (но, возможно, есть какие-то специальные типы для этого, про которые я не в курсе, поэтому ответ не пишу)

Comment: Я лично задумался об использовании базы, потому что мне хотелось бы иметь возможность отправлять сообщения на клиент из разных частей приложения. Вот думал что выбирать из базы как-то... правильнее что ли, чем импортировать массив из одного модуля в другой. В таком случае это имеет смысл или это лишняя возня с базой, которая ничего не улучшит?

Comment: Если разными частями приложения являются разные процессы, то для этого надо организовывать межпроцессное взаимодействие, чтобы один процесс работал с соединениями, а другие процессы отправляли этому процессу сообщения. Можно для этого написать свой велосипед на сокетах, можно для этого использовать готовые решения вроде RabbitMQ и Redis. А база тут никак не поможет. (Хотя можно отправлять сообщения через таблицу в базе, но это очень криво)

Comment: в java есть такое понятие как singleton. к которому можно иметь доступ из любой части кода. в нем и хранить весь массив подколючений по ws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Для пары тысяч одновременно подключенных подписчиков (участников чата) проходить массив список и т.д. вполне достаточно. В малых по посещаемости проектах решение более чем достаточно.
2. Для десятков тысяч одновременных коннектов, нужно усложнять алгоритм, подключать Redis+LUA (в редисе есть инструменты для организации подписок, можно использовать хеши, работает все очень быстро), можно использовать другие менеджеры очередей вроде RabbitMQ или Gearman. 
   Понятно что в одном чате больше тысячи участников уже никто держать не будет. Такие подходы нужны скорее для других задач, например для массовых оповещений больших групп посетителей о событиях или организации сообществ.
3. Когда посетителей становится очень много и одновременно нужно управлять корреспонденцией для сотен тысяч участников и более - оба варианта завалят серверы, какой бы пышной грядкой они не росли. Для организации общения (чата) нужно применять годами выточенные движки вроде jabber (он очень хорошо интегрируется с торнадо). 
   Можно пойти дальше занимаясь извращением на костылях в Си с помощью библиотеки вроде LevelDB (это очень быстрые и очень серьезные костыли, подойдут для чата масштабов мировой оргии).