# Одна переменная на несколько процессов в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, websocket, tornado, celery

По совету @andreymal из моего [предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426176/websocket-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0):

> Если разными частями приложения являются разные процессы, то для этого надо организовывать межпроцессное взаимодействие, чтобы один процесс работал с соединениями, а другие процессы отправляли этому процессу сообщения. Можно для этого написать свой велосипед на сокетах, можно для этого использовать готовые решения вроде RabbitMQ и Redis.

Пытаюсь реализовать межпроцессное взаимодействие при помощи celery.

**Исходные данные и какую задачу нужно решить:**
К серверу по вебсокетам должны подключаться клиенты (люди, использующие браузер) и ожидать сообщений от сервера.
На сервере время от времени срабатывает процесс, генерирующий это самое сообщение. Это сообщение (которое нужно отдать клиенту) можно попросить у процесса передать в указанный скрипт.

**Что для этого сделано:**

- Обработчик сокет-соединений на Python tornado;
- .py скрипт, которому на `stdin` подается сообщение от процесса, который генерирует само сообщение;
- функция-таск для celery, которая должна отправить сообщение в браузер.

То есть, процесс генерирует сообщение -> вызывает скрипт, передавая ему сообщение на `stdin` -> скрипт вызывает celery таск -> таск берет массив соединений и рассылает им сообщение.

**Суть проблемы:**
Сокет сервер складывает все соединения в массив, но этот массив оказывается пустым для celery таска.

**Собственно, вопрос**: как завести один массив на несколько процессов, или где я налажал, и как это делать правильно?

**UPD** добавил упрощенный код для понимания того, как и что есть.
Сокет-сервер на tornado:

```
class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    connections = []

    def open(self):
        self.__class__.connections.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def get_connections(cls):
        return cls.connections
```

и celery таск, который должен отправлять сообщения клиентам:

```
from handlers import SocketHandler

@celery.task
def send_msg(msg):
    for conn in SocketHandler.get_connections():
        conn.write_message(msg)
```

Но список полученный путем `SocketHandler.get_connections()` в файле с celery тасками оказывается пустым.
Запускаю все это в разных терминалах так:

```
(venv)$ python app.py  # это торнадо апп, импортирующий приведенный handlers
(venv)$ celery -A tasks worker
```

Comment: приведённый комментарий подразумевает, что сообщения к клиентами отправляют процессы, которые и так держат с ними соединения, и этим процессам другие процессы в системе могут давать комманды/генерировать события через систему, реализованную на RabbitMQ или Redis. То есть никакой массив соединений не надо расшаривать. Тема необъятная: что хочется реализовать: оповещение для внутрикорпоративного [чата](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/chatserver.py) или OTP сервер для MMO игры (типа [Astron](https://github.com/Astron/Astron))?

Comment: @jfs, хочется реализовать доставку электронной почты клиентам (принимает ее postfix). В тело вопроса добавил немного кода, чтобы было понятнее как сейчас есть.

Comment: 1. решение, предложенное в комментарии, *не* использует соединения, созданные в других процессах. То есть `connections` должен использоваться строго в том же процессе, который `append` вызывает (отступление: предположим мы используем `collections.OrderedDict`: если я делаю `from collections import OrderedDict`, то я не ожидаю, что в моём скрипте `OrderedDict` как-то поменяется только от того что другой процесс импортирует тот же модуль -- иначе было бы очень тяжело программировать с таким действием на расстоянии). 2. не вижу связи между посылкой почты и клиентами, подключенными по вебсокетам.

Comment: @jfs, по первому понятно.  
по второму - почта входящая. почта приходит ко мне на сервер и я хочу разослать ее подключенным клиентам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из описания проблемы и документации Celery я так понимаю, что таски выполняются в отдельных воркерах, которые может запускать сам Celery, но суть в том, что таск должен выполняться в одном процессе с сокет-сервером, тогда массив с сокетами ему будет виден. Пробежавшсь по диагонали по документации Celery, я подобного не нашёл; если это на нём и правда невозможно, то, видимо, стоит взять что-то попроще.

Вообще я представляю это как-то так (несколько кривенько, но, думаю, суть должна быть понятна):

```
def queue_thread():
    while thread_should_work():
        msg = redis.blpop("websocket_queue", timeout=5)
        if not msg:
            continue
        data = pickle.loads(msg[1])
        send_message_to_all_sockets(data)

Threading.thread(target=queue_thread).start()
```

Comment: На сколько понимаю, так можно периодически считывать задачи с редиса при помощи PeriodicCallback (http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback). Или лучше для этих целей такой вот цикл в треде?

Comment: Наверно, можно, но, если я правильно понимаю его назначение, это даст задержку в `callback_time` миллисекунд, в то время как ожидание следующего элемента с очереди (неважно какой, можно и не Redis) вернёт элемент (почти) сразу после его появления в очереди. Но не знаю, может, тут есть и что-то специально для таких очередей, но с Tornado работать не приходилось и ничего больше посоветовать не могу

Comment: @andreymall, с тредами пока самый рабочий вариант, так и сделаю. спасибо за помощь.